# Wi-fi problem (connected but not working)

Tags: wireless, 22.04, internet, connection, wifi-hardware-switch

My problem:

Wi-Fi is connected, the icon indicates this, but the internet doesn’t work for minutes but the icon still shows “connected” to Wi-Fi, then it works for minutes again and so it goes on.

```
anwarzadeh@anwarzadeh: $ nmcli
wlo1: connected to kv_37
        "Realtek RTL8821CE"
        wifi (rtw_8821ce), 20:2B:20:A9:F5:79, hw, mtu 1500
        ip4 default
        inet4 192.168.0.114/24
        route4 default via 192.168.0.1 metric 600
        route4 192.168.0.0/24 metric 600
        inet6 fe80::238d:703:dfcf:a282/64
        route6 fe80::/64 metric 1024

docker0: connected (externally) to docker0
        "docker0"
        bridge, 02:42:3F:C2:ED:CF, sw, mtu 1500
        inet4 172.17.0.1/16
        route4 172.17.0.0/16 metric 0
        route4 169.254.0.0/16 metric

lo: unmanaged
        "lo"
        loopback (unknown), 00:00:00:00:00:00, sw, mtu 65536

DNS configuration:
        servers: 192.168.0.1
        interface: wlo1

Use "nmcli device show" to get complete information about known devices and "nmcli connection show" to get an overview on active connection profiles.

Consult nmcli(1) and nmcli-examples(7) manual pages for complete usage details.
anwarzadeh@anwarzadeh:
```

P.S I apologize if haven’t detailed the problem but I hope you can help.

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager service`. Also do: `service NetworkManager status` and `service --status-all`.